# ¿Cómo escribir sobre otro texto?

Tags: c++

Hola estoy haciendo una tarea de programación donde use los métodos de ordenamiento como: Burbuja, quicksort, selección, etc.

En lo que me quede atorado es en; ¿Como puedo escribir sobre otro texto en la pantalla, me explico.

Supongamos que tengo en un arreglo:

```
arr[] {2,3,1};
```

Con ese arreglo debo hacer un histograma. Algo así:

```
  *
* *
* * *
```

Después debo usar mi método de ordenamiento para que se vea una animación.

Algo así:

```
    *
*   *
* * *

    *
  * *
* * *
```

y al final quede ordenado. Pero no se debe borrar la pantalla, sino que se sobre escriba encima.

Este es el método que uso para hacer las barras verticales.

```
for(int i = 20; i >= 0; i--)
{
  for(int j = 0; j < cuantos_datos; j++)
  {
    if (arr[j] > i) cout << "*";
    else cout << " ";
}
 cout << "\n";
```

Si alguien puede ayudarme, porfavor :).

Comment: Si no se puede borrar la pantalla, que pasa si vas a colocar uno de 1 de altura en donde habia uno de 2? No se va a ver el cambio. La pantalla la tienes que borrar por fuerza. Lo que quieres hacer depende de tu sistema operativo. Usa  `system` de `<cstdlib>` para llamar comandos nativos, y usa `cls` en windows y `clear` en las demas plataformas

Comment: la api de la consola te permite hacer esas cosas, pero el estándar de C++ no. Puedes conseguir ese efecto hablando directamente con la API de la consola o también, como eso no suele ser plato de buen gusto, puedes descargarte alguna librería de terceros que ya haya pasado por ese mal trago, como [ncurses](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses)